# access import csv to various tables based upon file name

Tags: ms-access, csv, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been searching various sites and links within stackoverflow and I haven't had much luck finding what I need. Currently I have an Access database with 3 tables called Oven1, Oven2, and Oven3. There are CSV files created daily for each one based upon an IP address and date field. What I would like to do, is create a macro or some other way to import the appropriate CSV from IP address in the file name to the correct Oven table and to also import the CSV dated for today. I also have to format one field to be short text or it won't import the data correctly. The IP's are 10.113.130.220 for Oven 3, .221 for Oven 2, and .222 for Oven3. I am wondering if this can even be done or would I be better off trying to do this via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the example, you can format a string variable if you wish to grab the current date.

```
Private Sub GetOvenData()
   Dim strDate As String
   strDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
   DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "Oven1", "\\10.113.130.220\folder\" & strDate & ".csv", 1
   DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "Oven2", "\\10.113.130.221\folder\" & strDate & ".csv", 1
   DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "Oven3", "\\10.113.130.222\folder\" & strDate & ".csv", 1
End Sub
```

Change `\folder\` to wherever your files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's easy. It would look like this:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "spec-oven1", "oven1", "c:\...\10.113.130.220.cvs"
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "spec-oven2", "oven2", "c:\...\10.113.130.221.cvs"
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "spec-oven3", "oven3", "c:\...\10.113.130.222.cvs"
```

The spec-oven1 is a saved import specification. Create it by first importing your file manually, and saving the import spec.